# Loop over files in directory with if statement (batch file)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, compilation

I'm trying to create a bat file to compile all of the .java files in a directory and to run the class called Main (and output to tulemused.txt) I was able to do this for a single .java file with a set name but I don't know how to use batch scripting well enough to loop over all of the files.

```
@ECHO on

FOR /d %%f DO IF NOT %%f=="compile.bat" javac -encoding utf-8 %%f

java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 Main > tulemused.txt

@ECHO off
```

This is how far I got

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this works even better since java wants to compile all of the classes at once but credit to Wasif for fixing the original loop

```
@ECHO on
set string=javac -encoding utf-8
 FOR /r %%f In (*.java) DO call :concat %%~nf
%string%
set /P name="What is the name of the class with the main method? "
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 %name% >result.txt
pause

:concat
set string=%string% %1.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ECHO on
 FOR /r %%f In (*) DO IF NOT "%%~nf"=="compile.bat" javac -encoding utf-8 "%%~f" 
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 Main >tulemused.txt
```

Comment: _I'm surprised that this has been marked as accepted, when there's clearly something which was correct in the question code, which isn't in this._ The batch file is not called, `compile.bat.cmd` or `compile.bat.bat`!